# What is the Connection URL to connect to ethereum kovan to connect with my smart contract

Tags: java, ethereum, smartcontracts

I am beginner trying to work with ethereum network and I have a contract deployed on Kovan test network. I am trying to write a sample java program which connects to this kovan network and interacts with the contract that I deployed at a specific address. I am not sure what is the kovan network connection URL to be used in this case.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your own Ethereum node.

[Here is the list of providers](https://www.linkedin.com/in/harsh-udasi-522720101/).

Comment: Seems like you posted an incorrect link - this goes to some person's LinkedIn profile. Please edit your question with the corrected link.